# Refactor += expression

Tags: javascript, object, operators

***Code***

```
 const updatePlayerPosition = ({ x, y, collided }) => {
    setPlayer((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      pos: { x: (prev.position.x += x), y: (prev.position.y += y) },
      collided,
    }));
  };
```

***Problem***

EsLint sign this line

```
  pos: { x: (prev.position.x += x), y: (prev.position.y += y) },
```

as "No return error" and [this is the link](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign) of the explanation.

I tried to read it and tried to apply the solution of Eslint but i cannot compile it.

***Question***

How can i refactor the line

```
  pos: { x: (prev.position.x += x), y: (prev.position.y += y) },
```

without having errors ?

Comment: To me, this even looks like an error. Why would you go through the hassle of creating an entire new object, just with a new position, when you then also edit the position on the old one? Why not just `x: prev.position.x + x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to update the position of player by adding x and y values to the previous position. `prev.position.x += x`, this is mutating the prev object, but you just need to return an updated pos with new values of x and y.

**Wrong way**:

```
pos: { x: (prev.position.x += x), y: (prev.position.y += y) },
```

**Right way**:

```
pos: { x: (prev.position.x + x), y: (prev.position.y + y) },
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the current code works as intended, and you *do* want to mutate `prev.position`, and the issue is just the linter warning, the problem is you have an assignment which is being parsed as an expression, which arguably makes the code harder to read. Generally, put assignments as standalone statements instead:

```
const updatePlayerPosition = ({ x, y, collided }) => {
  setPlayer((prev) => {
    prev.position.x += x;
    prev.position.y += y;
    return {
      ...prev,
      pos: { x: prev.position.x, y: prev.position.y },
      collided,
    };
  });
};
```